# Get first json object from response rest service by Beanshell in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I get this JSON response from my web service:

```
[
    {
        "type": "022",
        "sendDate": "2020-11-09 12:43:07",
        "message": "test1",
        "id": 8035,
    },
    {
        "notificationType": "023",
        "sendDate": "2020-11-09 11:40:02",
        "message": "test2 ",
        "id": 8034,
    },...
]
```

Now by **Beanshell** in JMeter I want to pass first id into new request so in JSR223 PostProcessor i write a simple print like this:

```
import com.eclipsesource.json.*;
String jsonString = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
log.info("value=" + jsonString);
JsonArray inbox =  Json.parse(jsonString).asArray();
//String id_BSH = ((JSONObject) storeArray.get(0)).getAsString("id");
//vars.put("id_BSH", pickup);
```

but i got this error :

```
2020-11-10 17:59:55,245 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import com.eclipsesource.json.*; String jsonString = prev.getResponseDataAsStrin . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Class: JsonArray not found in namespace : at Line: 4 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``import com.eclipsesource.json.*; String jsonString = prev.getResponseDataAsStrin . . . '' : JsonArray 
 in inline evaluation of: ``import com.eclipsesource.json.*; String jsonString = prev.getResponseDataAsStrin . . . '' at line number 4
    at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.evalSource(BshScriptEngine.java:93) ~[bsh-2.0b6.jar:2.0b6 2016-02-05 05:16:19]
    at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.eval(BshScriptEngine.java:46) ~[bsh-2.0b6.jar:2.0b6 2016-02-05 05:16:19]
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:233) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:224) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.extractor.JSR223PostProcessor.process(JSR223PostProcessor.java:45) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPostProcessors(JMeterThread.java:940) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:572) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_202]
```

Comment: did you had minimal-json jar to JMeter classpath?

Comment: Yes i added `minimal-json` to lib jmeter  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/w5yG2DFsVq/   @user7294900

Comment: Jar isn't in lib folder

Comment: What folder i have to put? @user7294900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard [Groovy "is the new black"](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black), moreover you [should not be using Beanshell since JMeter 3.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so you can go for Groovy's [JsonSlurper](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) class and store the first ID into a variable with this one-liner:

```
vars.put("id_BSH", new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).get(0).id as String)
```

More information: [Apache Groovy - Parsing and Producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)

Comment: `Since JMeter 3.1, we advise switching from BeanShell to JSR223 Test Elements`.I am using JSR223 https://pasteboard.co/JzKLkUs.png @DmitriT

Comment: You're using a JSR223 test element with beanshell language and you're supposed to be using groovy